# Fastest Implementation of polynomial interpolation?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Suppose I am working over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and have $n$ points in the point-value representation $(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})$. What is the fastest way to do polynomial interpolation and convert this to the coefficient form, that is, obtain the coefficients of polynomial $f()$ such that $f(i)=x_i, i \in \{0,\cdots,n-1\}$ ? Based on my understanding, it would take $O(n^2)$ computations using the Lagrange interpolation method. If the point-value representations were for the roots of unity then we could use FFT to get the coefficients in $O(nlogn)$ but in the general case which is the most efficient method? More specifically, can we do better than $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polynomial interpolation can be done via multiplying a Vandermonde matrix (or its inverse) by your coefficient/evaluation vector --- it is a change of basis on the vector space of polynomials of bounded degree. If this matrix has special structure (such as when the evaluation points are roots of unity --- here the matrix is Toeplitz) this matrix-vector multiplication can be done faster (in $O(n\log n)$ time) this is precisely the FFT. But any choice of evaluation points such that you have fast(er) matrix-vector multiplication algorithms suffices. This might give you a slightly more general question to investigate, which might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  The problem I am investigating, the polynomial is obtained in the point-value form only for fixed points, ie., $i=0,\cdots,n-1$. Given this fixed constraint, does that mean $O(n^2)$ is the best we can do?

Comment: Is there a domain-specific reason for these evaluation points? I see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/96112/fast-implementations-of-verifiable-shamirs-secret-shares) that you are doing a variant of Shamir's secret sharing. I don't think Shamir's requires the evaluation points are $\{0,\dots,n\}$ (any other subset of evaluation points should work) --- does your particular application require these points, rather than say $\{1, \omega^1,\dots,\omega^n\}$ for a suitable root of unity $\omega$?

Comment: I think you are right, I just need any $n$ separate points, does not necessarily need to be $\{0,\cdots,n\}$, roots of unity would work as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: The only point I would mention then is that you need to be doing arithmetic over a finite field for shamir's, so you cannot use a literal (complex) root of unity. Instead, you should look into what is generally called the "Number-Theoretic Transform", which is essentially an FFT where you use a root of unity within $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Not only does Shamir not require that the points be $\{0,\ldots,n\}$, but the standard Shamir uses the value at $0$ for the secret, so it can't be one of the points. But then this whole question is a distraction, because evaluating at $0$ does not require calculating all of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

In the special case of these evaluation points you can easily get the coefficients to write the polynomial as $\sum_0^{n-1}c_j\binom{x}j$ .

You find this explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial)  , among other places. It just involves taking the differences and their differences etc. So for $6,10,7,12$ you would take the differences $4,-3,5$ then $-7,8$ then $15$ Yielding the cubic $$6\binom{x}0+4\binom{x}1-7\binom{x}2+15\binom{x}3.$$

I said easily, not quickly. That is still $O(n^2)$, but just subtractions. And if you want the standard coefficients there is still work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Input: $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, . . . , \alpha_n, \beta_1, \beta_2, . . . , \beta_n \in \mathbb{R}$

Output: $c_0, c_1, . . . , c_{n-1}$ such that $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i x^i$ and $f(α_j) = β_j$

We can assume we know the polynomials:

$\hspace{2.25cm}Z_1 = \prod_{i = 1}^{\frac{n}{2}} (x - \alpha_i)\hspace{0.5cm}$ and $\hspace{0.5cm}Z_2 = \prod_{i = \frac{n}{2} + 1}^{n} (x - \alpha_i) $

We want to find $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that:

$\hspace{1cm} f = f_{2} \cdot Z_{1} + f_{1} \cdot Z_{2}, \hspace{0.5cm}$    with $\hspace{0.5cm}deg(f_1) < \frac{n}{2}\hspace{0.5cm}$ and $\hspace{0.5cm}deg(f_2) < \frac{n}{2}$

We see that $f_2(\alpha_i) = \frac{\beta_i}{Z_1(\alpha_i)}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq \frac{n}{2}$, and $f_1(\alpha_i) = \frac{\beta_i}{Z_2(\alpha_i)}$ for all $\frac{n}{2} + 1 \leq i \leq n$.
So we can solve for $f_1$ and $f_2$ using interpolation of half the size; and the values of $\{Z_1(\alpha_i)\}$’s and $\{Z_2(\alpha_i)\}$’s can be computed using polynomial evaluation at multiple points in $O(n·ln^2 n)$.
Looking at the recursion cost we see that the total cost is again nearly linear time with respect to $n$.